# Adding columns in sql server with transformed data from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in sql server db which has a 'nvarchar' datatype column with datetime data.

I want to add two more columns to the table, one having the whole datetime data in 'datetime' datatype and the other column should have just the date in 'datetime' datatype

I have around 5 million rows in the table.

The nvarchar data looks like this: 2013-03-20 00:00:50

I would sincerely appreciate if someone could help me with a sql command which would do this..

Thanks

Comment: First of all, why are you storing datetime data in `nvarchar` type. You should be using `datetime` instead.

Comment: @Rahul not my data originally.. as I said it already has 5mil + rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to first alter the table, then update it.

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE ADD DATETIME_COL DATETIME
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE ADD DATE_COL DATE

UPDATE YOUR_TABLE 
SET 
  DATE_COL = CAST(NVCHAR_DATE AS DATE), 
  DATETIME_COL = CAST(NVCHAR_DATE AS DATETIME)
```

However, storing the date as a separate column seems a bit redundant. Maybe a computed column would be a better choice:

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE ADD COMNPUTED_DATE_COL AS CAST(DATETIME_COL AS DATE)
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad013/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
update table x
set dateColumnWithTime = cast(MyVarcharDate as datetime), 
    datecolumnWithoutTime = DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, cast(MyVarcharDate as datetime)), 0)
```

Output:

```
dateColumnWithTime      datecolumnWithoutTime
----------------------- -----------------------
2013-03-20 00:00:50.000 2013-03-20 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all storing `datetime` type as `nvarchar` is wrong. Instead of storing the the data as two more column(s); you get the data from your `nvarchar` column and display it accordingly like below and that way you can avoid doing `update` on 5M rows

```
SELECT CAST(nvarchar_column as DATETIME) as datetime_col,
CAST(nvarchar_column as DATE) as date_col
from my_5m_rows_table
```

Comment: It might be a better option to do a one time update and add a proper datetime column though instead of having to cast whenever the date needs to be queried.

Comment: If that's the case then much better option is doing a `ctas` or `insert into select from` to a different table.

Comment: @Rahul can u plz give an example of 'ctas or insert into select from to a different table'

Comment: @Arnab, see here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/04/30/sql-server-ctas-create-table-as-select-what-is-ctas/

Comment: @Rahul Why would it be better to create a new table instead of altering the existing? Doing a ctas or similar would duplicate the 5 million row table, plus every query/sp/function w/e that references the original table would have to be changed. I really don't see any upside to doing this instead of alter/update. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, avoiding an `alter` + `update`. Also, after the CTAS is done just drop the old table and rename the new to old one. May not be too good but at least a bit better. hope so.

Comment: @Rahul And what if the table is referenced by foreign keys in other tables? Then you have to remove the constraints to be able to do a drop/rename. It just seems like a more expensive operation, but lets agree to disagree :)